# Java.lang.illegalstateexception when trying to hide Linearlayouts in Android

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to hide 2 LinearLayouts using (View.Invisible). LinearLayouts have 1-1 textviews in them respectively. Any Suggestions? Below i have attached the MainActivity class, an AsyncTask class and the Logcat Text. I get the error while i am trying to add LinearLayouts to an Arraylist (this much i have researched :P... Commenting it will give no error)... Thanks in advance

MainActivity

```
package com.abhishek.ally2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textview;
    String header;
    Handler handler;
    ImageView image ;
    asyncNetwork task = null;
    ProgressBar pg;
    List<String> response = null;
    List<LinearLayout> ll =new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        handler = new Handler();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void login(View v)
    {
        boolean check = true;
        String id = null;
        int length;
        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.allyId);
        if(textview.getText().length() == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Ally ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            check = false;
        }

        for (char c : textview.getText().toString().toCharArray())
        {
            if (!Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(check)
        {
            id = textview.getText().toString();
            id = "id="+id;
            length = id.length();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            pg = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status); 
            image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageFrnds);
            ll.add((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.emailll1));
            ll.add((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.smsll1));
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ally);
            task =  new asyncNetwork(this, textview, new Handler(), image, pg, ll);
            task.execute("easyvote.co.in", "80", "POST /ally.php HTTP/1.0\nHost: easyvote.co.in\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\nContent-Length: "+ length +"\n\n" + id + "\n");   
        }

    }

}
```

asyncNetwork.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.abhishek.ally2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class asyncNetwork extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    Context myCtx;
    Friend friend ;
    TextView status;
    ImageView image;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable r;
    String responseLine;
    List<String> response = null;
    List<LinearLayout> ll = null;
    ProgressBar pg;
    boolean data = false;
    asyncNetwork(Context context, TextView status, Handler handler, ImageView image, ProgressBar pg, List<LinearLayout> ll)
    {
        this.myCtx = context;
        this.status = status;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.data = false;
        this.image = image;
        this.pg = pg;
        this.ll = ll;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... mainData) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String host = mainData[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(mainData[1]);
        String data = mainData[2];
        Socket client = null;
        DataOutputStream os = null;
        BufferedReader is = null;
        try 
        {
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                this.response = new ArrayList<String>();
                this.data = false;
                client = new Socket(host, port);
                os = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                is= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                if(client != null && os != null && is != null)
                {
                    //Log.d("Response", data);
                    os.writeBytes(data);
                    responseLine = is.readLine();
                    if(!responseLine.contains("200"))
                    {
                        r = new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                status.setText("404 Error :(");

                            }

                        };
                        this.handler.post(r);
                    }
                    while((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Log.d("Response", responseLine);
                        if(this.data)
                        {
                            response.add(responseLine);
                        }
                        if(responseLine.contains("###start"))
                        {
                            this.data = true;
                        }
                    }
                    os.close();
                    is.close();
                    client.close();
                    Log.d("Count value", "value" + response.size());
                    friend =  new Friend(response.get(0));
                    if(friend.isOnline())
                    {
                        Log.d("Count value", friend.name + " is online :)");
                        //status.setText(friend.name + " is online :)");
                        r = new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                status.setText(friend.name + " is Online :)");
                                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.tapus);
                                pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            }
                        };
                        this.handler.post(r);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("Count value", friend.name + " is Offline :)");

                        r = new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.tapus);
                                status.setText(friend.name + " is Offline :(");
                                pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                //ll[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                //ll[1].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        };
                        this.handler.post(r);
                    }

                }
            }
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Logcat data

```
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at com.abhishek.ally2.MainActivity.login(MainActivity.java:70)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  ... 11 more
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
07-04 22:39:19.875: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  ... 15 more
```

Comment: That's a lot code. Your exception tells you where to look at: `MainActivity.java` line 70. You casted an object to something it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Can you indicate which is line 70 of `MainActivity` and post your xml? It looks like you may be using the wrong `id` for the wrong `View`

Comment: Seems like your wrong id is emailll1. What type of view is it?

Comment: sorry... I did a blunder... the id is of a TextView... thanks for the Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears to be in these two lines

```
    ll.add((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.emailll1));
    ll.add((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.smsll1));
```

You are trying to cast a `View` to a `LinearLayout` and by the logcat they seem to be `TextViews` (at least the first one which would be throwing the error).

If this is the case then you need to change what you are adding here to the `ArrayList` to add an actual `LinearLayout` that you have.